# Unterschied zwischen Acht und Achtung?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

Gibt es vielleicht einen feinen Unterschied zwischen diesen Sätzen:

- Bei der medizinischen Versorgung wird kaum (Acht/Achtung) auf die Verschiedenheit zwischen Männer und Frauen gegeben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Acht geben / achtgeben (auf)* ist eine mögliche Kombination, um auszudrücken, dass man vorsichtig sein und sich auf bestimmte Details konzentrieren sollte. Es ist inhaltlich vergleichbar mit *aufpassen*:

> Gib (darauf) acht, dass du nichts danebengießt.

Ich benutze es z.B. für Warnungen und für ein beschreibendes *nicht aus den Augen lassen* oder *vorsichtig umgehen mit*, also bezogen auf einzelne risikohaltige Situationen. Im Beispielssatz ist aber kein situationelles Risiko gemeint, sondern ein generelles, grundsätzliches Nicht-auf-dem-Schirm-Haben. Für meine Begriffe würde hier das Verb *beachten* besser passen:

> (Es wird inzwischen vielfach kritisiert, dass) bei der medizinischen Versorgung die Unterschiede zwischen Männern und Frauen **kaum beachtet** werden.

Noch besser fände ich

> Den Unterschieden zwischen Männern und Frauen **wurde** in der Medizin bislang **zu wenig Beachtung geschenkt**

oder

> Den Unterschieden zwischen Männern und Frauen **wurde** in der medizinischen Versorgung bisher **nicht ausreichend Rechnung getragen**,

was bedeutet, dass diese Unterschiede nicht ausreichend berücksichtigt wurden.

DWDS erwähnt allerdings auch ein '*Achtung geben auf*' als "veraltet", mit einem Beispiel von Goethe. Ich kannte diesen Sprachgebrauch bis jetzt nicht.

Ein anderes '*achten*' bedeutet 'respektieren' oder 'sehr schätzen' bzw., in Kombination mit 'gering' (*ein Menschenleben wird dort geringgeachtet / gering geachtet*) das Gegenteil, ähnlich 'verachten'.

Das Substantiv *Achtung* kommt im Alltag hauptsächlich in Warnrufen als (Quasi-)Einwortsatz vor:

> Achtung, Achtung! Hier spricht die Polizei.

Es ist eine Aufforderung zum Genau-Zuhören oder zum Sich-Konzentrieren auf die Situation.

In den von Guidot erwähnten Kombinationen beschreibt es eine Ehrerweisung: '*jemandem Achtung erweisen*' heißt 'ihn respektvoll behandeln'. Es entspricht in vielen Fällen dem Substantiv '*Wertschätzung*' (= eine hohe Meinung haben von) und passt daher nicht zu dem Beispiel.

Answer (score 3):

Ja, nur *Acht geben* ist richtig.

*Achtung* wird eher im Sinn von *Hochachtung* verwendet, und typischerweise mit *entgegenbringen*/*zollen* verwendet, siehe den Abschnitt *typische Verbindungen* von [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Achtung)

Comment: Dahingegen ist der Ausruf `Achtung!` im Sinne von `Gib Acht!` gemeint.